# Python replace - Treat multiple instances as one

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to replace all the carriage returns with a command for incoming lines. It works fine, except when multiple carriage returns exist. I see no information in python's string.replace() function on how to treat multiple instances of the same item as though they are one. Is this possible?

For instance, this line:

```
This is\nA sentence\nwith multiple\nbreaklines\n\npython.
```

Should end up like this:

```
This is, A sentence, with multiple, breaklines, python.
```

But it actually turns into this:

```
This is, A sentence, with multiple, breaklines, , python.
```

Comment: It would help in identifying the problem with your code to actually see it.

Comment: You could always just manually iterate the list and replace them. A regex might be useful here too.

Comment: @Carcigenicate is correct: use a regular expression, with any number of newlines treated as a single match: "\n"+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex.

```
In [48]: mystr = "This is\nA sentence\nwith multiple\nbreaklines\n\npython."
In [49]: re.sub(r'\n+', ', ', mystr)
Out[49]: 'This is, A sentence, with multiple, breaklines, python.'
```

The regex pattern matches where there's one or more `\n`'s next to each other and replaces them with a `,`.